# Internet speed affects the API process though its local ip

Tags: android, localhost, offlineapps

My application works offline just wifi range is required.
I am accessing data from server which is in same LAN as wifi router.

Problem is as below.

If net connection is removed from wifi then it works fine. API access dosent take much time. Once net connected to wifi then net speed affect the API process time though I am pointing to local ip.

Is there any explicit configuration I need to make in Router setting to process local request first when net is connected

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `If net connection is removed from wifi`. ?? What are you doing exactly? Removing a cable from your router?

Comment: Yes am removing the cable from router. input cable from router not output cable.

Comment: Try a different router. A loose cable should not have any effect.

Comment: SetUp is fine router is also ok. It seems router search for best path in routing table though its a local ip.

Comment: Try a different rooter.